# Regexp matching in group with special characters

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I have a String that is something like this:

```
A20130122.0000+0000-0015+0000_name
```

Then I would like to extract this information:

The `20130122.0000+0000-0015+0000` that will be parsed to a date later on.
And the final part which is `name`.

So I am using in Java something like this:

```
String regexpOfdate = "[0-9]{8}\\.[0-9]{4}\\+[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}\\+[0-9]{4}";
String regexpOfName = "\\w+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format("A(%s)_(%s)", regexpOfdate, regexpOfName));
Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);
String date = m.group(0);
String name = m.group(1);
```

But I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling `Matcher#find` or `Matcher#matches` methods after this line:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);
```

Try this code:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);
if (m.find()) {
    String date = m.group(1);
    String name = m.group(2);
    System.out.println("Date: " + date + ", name: " + name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is working using this `String date = m.group(1);
    String name = m.group(2);`

Comment: According to the JavaDoc for find() method:
Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches
the pattern. This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if
a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has 
not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous
match. If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
start, end, and group methods.
@return true if, and only if, a subsequence of the input
sequence matches this matcher's pattern.
So you need to call find().

Answer (score 1):

`Matcher#group` will throw `IllegalStateException` if the matcher's regex hasn't yet
been applied to its target text, or if the previous application was not successful.

`Matcher#find` applies the matcher's regex to the current region  of the matcher's target text, returning a Boolean indicating whether a match is found.

**[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171445/how-matcher-find-works)**

You can try this :

```
    String theString="A20130122.0000+0000-0015+0000_name";
    String regexpOfdate = "([0-9]{8})\\.[0-9]{4}\\+[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}\\+[0-9]{4}";
    String regexpOfName = "(\\w+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format("A(%s)_(%s)", regexpOfdate, regexpOfName));
    Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);
    if(m.find()){
      String date = m.group(2);
      String name = m.group(3);
      System.out.println("date: "+date);
      System.out.println("name: "+name);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
date: 20130122
name: name
```

Refer **[Grouping in REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex)**