# Getting value of string inside some regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have code like this:

```
String s1 = "((${adapterKind=VMWARE, resourceKind=VirtualMachine, metric=disk|usage_average}*${this, metric=summary|oversizedVMCount})+${this, metric=summary|poweredOffVMCount})";
//Some code

I want output inside

String[] s2 = {${adapterKind=VMWARE, resourceKind=VirtualMachine, metric=disk|usage_average}, ${this, metric=summary|oversizedVMCount}, ${this, metric=summary|poweredOffVMCount}};
```

Basically I want to get all those values which is with "${...}". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s1 = "((${adapterKind=VMWARE, resourceKind=VirtualMachine, metric=disk|usage_average}*${this, metric=summary|oversizedVMCount})+${this, metric=summary|poweredOffVMCount})";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[^}]*\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
while(m.find())
    //here you have the captured texts, 
    //you can put into array/collection as you like
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

this output:

```
${adapterKind=VMWARE, resourceKind=VirtualMachine, metric=disk|usage_average}
${this, metric=summary|oversizedVMCount}
${this, metric=summary|poweredOffVMCount}
```

Comment: what will be regex compile for "sum(...)"?

Comment: @ShashiRanjan what do you mean? sum of what? regex cannot do `sum()`

Comment: Thanks, I got what I needed, "sum\\(.*\\)"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the java.util.regex.Matcher#find() method.

[This question has a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171445/how-matcher-find-works)