# How to replicate a functioning indexOf method without using indexOf in Java?

Tags: java

I want to find the index of certain letters in a string without using the indexOf method. I was able to do this, but I also want any letters that are not in the word/string to return a value of -1. I tried an if statement and it returns -1 as well as the index of the letter. I just want one or the other. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class randomtest {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
            String text = "Cheeki Breeki";
            String letterToFind = "C";
            Pattern word = Pattern.compile(letterToFind);
            Matcher match = word.matcher(text); 
            if (!letterToFind.equals(text)) {
                System.out.println("-1");
            }

            while (match.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found letter at index "+ match.start());
        }

       } 

}
```

Comment: "I also posted an image instead of the code" but why? Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557))

Comment: don't post an image, post code. click [edit], paste code. then select it, and click `[{ }]` button above.

Comment: I added the code now

Comment: Maybe this can help if you are using `Matcher.find()` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171445/how-matcher-find-works

Comment: Why would you want to avoid using indexOf(). And why use a regexp instead? That's a bit like using a Boeing to go to the store 200 meters away because you're not allowed to use your bike or car. How about using a loop to compare each character of the string with the character to find?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the below code wrong. As `String letterToFind = "C";` and `String text = "Cheeki Breeki";` you are comparing these two in your `if` statement which will always be wrong either the character is there in string or not. because in one string you have the **complete string** and in another variable you have **characterToFind**.

```
if (!letterToFind.equals(text)) {
    System.out.println("-1");
}
```

Use the code as below, use boolean flag to check if character is found.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        String text = "Cheeki Breeki";
        String letterToFind = "A";
        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(letterToFind);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

        boolean letterFound = false;

        while (match.find()) {
            letterFound = true;
            System.out.println("Found letter at index " + match.start());
        }

        if (!letterFound) {
            System.out.println("-1");
        }
    }
```