# How to use Pattern.compile with spaces in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with matching the two words with a space between them in [`Pattern.compile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) in Java.

My string is `"What is your name?"`.

**My code:**

```
String namee = "What is your name?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("What is|Address is");
if (pattern.matcher(namee).find())
{
    if (namee.equals("What is"))
    {
        namee = "name";
    }
}
```

what I am trying to achieve if a string consist `"What is"` then the string itself should change to `"name"`. But its not wotking with space...

Comment: Why would `if(namee.equals("What is"))` ever be true if you never change content of `namee`?

Comment: didnt get you @Pshemo

Comment: @doe He means that you assigned `namee = "What is your name?";`,
so esentilally you are checking the conditional: `if("What is your name?".equals("What is"))` which is obviously not true...

Comment: At `String namee = "What is your name?";` you set `namee` to contain `"What is your name?"`. Then you never change what `namee` holds (unless you assume that `pattern.matcher(namee).find()` may affect it, which is false) so it still holds ` "What is your name?"`. At `namee.equals("What is")` you are checking if string held by `namee` is equal to `What is` (which is not), it *starts with* `What is` but is not equal to it. What are you trying to achieve with `if(namee.equals("What is"))`?

Comment: @Pshemo updated the ques

Comment: Take a look at YCF_L answer. Matcher allows you to traverse over text and search for pattern. If it `find()` anything we can access matched parts via `matcher.group(indexOfSpecificGroup)` or `matcher.group()` to access whole match. So you want to text result of `matcher.group()` instead of whole `namee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution1**

You can use `Matcher` and then check with the `matcher.group()` like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("What is|Address is");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(namee);
if (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group().equals("What is")) {
        namee = "name";
    }
}
```

---

**Solution2**

If you want to check if your string contain `What is` or `Address is`, then you can easily use :

```
if(namee.contains("What is")){
    namee = "What is";
}else if (namee.contains("Address is")){
    namee = "....";
}
```

---

**Solution3**

If you want to check if your string start with `What is` or `Address is` then you can use :

```
if(namee.startsWith("What is")){
    namee = "What is";
}else if (namee.startsWith("Address is")){
    namee = "....";
}
```

Comment: I am betting tactical down-voting.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: solution 1 and i am trying second now but third answer is not i wanted

Comment: @doe "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found" is thrown when you try to access `group` before it was able to match anything. Did you invoke `find()` before? Did result of that method was `true`?

Comment: yes my code is 
  `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("What is");
                if (pattern.matcher(namee).find())
                {
                 if(pattern.matcher(namee).group().equals("What is"))
                 {
                  namee = "name";
                 }
}`

Comment: @doe if i can hit you i will (jock), this is not my solution try to copy past my answer please, it should work with you :)

Comment: @doe i use this `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("What is|Address is");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(namee);
if (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group().equals("What is")) {
        namee = "name";
    }
}` not what you already do focus a little please

Comment: tell me what is the differnece b/w `pattern.matcher(namee).find()` AND Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(namee); and (matcher.find())...

Comment: @doe to understand more i suggest to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171445/how-matcher-find-works, another think you can up-vote the answer if that help you

Comment: @doe Each time you execute `pattern.matcher(namee)` you create *new* Matcher (which happens to traverse same text `namee`). So you create one in `if (pattern.matcher(namee).find())` and *second one* in `if(pattern.matcher(namee).group().equals("What is"))`. That second one didn't traverse `namee` yet (since `find()` was invoked on first one) which is why you see that exception. Create *one* Matcher, store it in variable like `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(namee)` and use that `matcher` to `find()` match for regex, and then get that match from `group()` (like answer shows).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (to be safe; better code readability as well IMHO):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(What is)|(Address is)")
```

but the following code feels wrong:

```
if (namee.equals("What is"))
...
```

you probably want to use instead the [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) you just created. For instance:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(namee);
if (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group().equals("What is")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `|` has higher precedence than space (which is not one of regex metacharacters) so there is no need to explicitly add groups via parenthesis. Regex `What is|Address is` is already seen as `(?:What is)|(?:Address is)`.

Comment: @Pshemo Just to be safe... also provides better readability as well IMHO. Operator precedence can be tricky to get right ;)

Comment: what the coincidence the second part is totally similar to my solution, i think for that i get down-vote, the member maybe think that i take it from you, but this is not true

Comment: @YCF_L Hmmm… I mentioned the `Matcher` in my first draft but OP was still confused. So I used the somewhat standard code for this situation. We probably wrote at the same time bro ;) Happy hacking!

Comment: ...and not sure why I was downvoted as well :-( Anyway, hope OP issue is solved for good by now guys ;)